# How can I host a server with express.js and socket.io with IONOS?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, ionos

I'm trying to establish a web socket with my website and the user but I can't find anything of where to put the files or how to host them. Can IONOS host the server or do I have to host the server and just redirect the domain to my computer ip adress, and if so how do I do that?
I can't find anything about hosting a server with ionos so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Buy a VPS/VM on IONOS and install node.js there. They do not support "native" hosting of node.js services.